# ext2 file system and Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, filesystems, mount, ext2

I have Solaris 10 installed on computer and I have USB flash drive with ext2fs partition. I want to mount flash drive and do this:
1) Download FSWpart and FSWfsmisc packages
2) Install:

```
root~#gzcat FSWpart.tar.gz | tar xvf -

root~#gzcat FSWfsmisc.tar.gz | tar xvf -

root~#pkgadd -d . FSWpart

root~#pkgadd -d . FSWfsmisc
```

3) Run prtpart util
4) And mount:

```
root~#mount -F ext2fs /dev/dsk/c1d0p3 /mnt/usb
```

After that I can see file-tree in /mnt/usb, but it mounted only as read-only.
 May be anybody know, other way to  mount ext2 in Solaris whit read-write mode?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to copy the files from /mnt/usb and then extract them?

```
root~#mount -F ext2fs /dev/dsk/c1d0p3 /mnt/usb
root~#mkdir /tmp/patch 
root~#cp /mnt/usb/FSWpart.tar.gz /mnt/usb/FSWfsmisc.tar.gz /tmp/patch
root~#cd /tmp/patch 
root~#gzcat FSWpart.tar.gz | tar xvf -
root~#gzcat FSWfsmisc.tar.gz | tar xvf -
root~#pkgadd -d . FSWpart
root~#pkgadd -d . FSWfsmisc
```